# Use of checkstyle.xml in diffplug/spotless

Tags: code-formatting, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin, google-java-format, spotless

I have a checkstyle.xml file to check for formatting violations . Is there any way to provide checkstyle.xml as a input to diffplug/spotless formatter . Java8 is being used and spotless verison is 2.11.0 . If this is possible using spotless::apply we can remove all the style violations . Maven version is 3.6.3 . Currently google-java-format is being used .